# Optaplanner - Multiple threads with multiple solvers

Tags: java, multithreading, optaplanner

I'm running Optaplanner under multiple threads trying to take advantage of multiple CPU cores. The idea is: let the optimizer off for a limited amount of time, pick the best solution across the threads, possibly iterate (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349458/solving-with-multiple-initial-solutions-in-parallel)). I'm aware this is not the same as running the optimization itself in parallel, and I'm also aware parallelizing the optimization is in Optaplanner roadmap. Here's the problem - for the same amount of time I get consistently lower scores when I'm running parallel. The more threads I use, the worse it gets. For the sake of reproducing the problem I changed the `CloudBalancingHelloWorld` class, something the likes of:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SolverFactory solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml");
    CloudBalance unsolvedCloudBalance = new CloudBalancingGenerator().createCloudBalance(400, 1200);
    CloudBalance[] cbarray = new CloudBalance[8];
    Arrays.fill(cbarray, unsolvedCloudBalance);
    Arrays.stream(cbarray)
            .parallel()
            .map(cb -> {
                Solver solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
                solver.solve(cb);
                return solver.getBestSolution();
            })
            .forEach(
                    solvedCloudBalance -> System.out
                            .println("\nSolved cloudBalance with 400 computers and 1200 processes:\n"
                                    + solvedCloudBalance.getScore()));
    ;
}
```

And in the configuration

```
 <termination>
    <secondsSpentLimit>30</secondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>
```

I thought that might have been a performance issue however I logged the amount of moves and they are the same per thread - also I have 12 physical cores available on the machine and way more RAM than I need. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you're running 8 in parallel on a 12 core machine? What if you run 6 on a 12 core machine? I'd leave at least 1 CPU for the OS. On hyper-threaded core (or something called like that), I recall a case that the real number of independent cpu's is the cpu count divided by 2. So that's why I am asking of the behavior with 6 in parallel.

Comment: What the ACC (Average Calculate Count) with 1 thread, with 6 threads and with 8 threads?

Comment: How do you make sure each CB config in the parallel threads are different? just environmentMode production? I'd recommend actually using different algo's (LA vs SA vs TS) with different parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! In order: 1) I actually have 12 physical cores (hyper-threaded to 24)  so my guess is - I'm not short of resources here. I also tried with 2, 4 and 8 threads and the more threads the worse it gets. 2) I'll get the ACC and post back 3) yes, I'm using environment mode production. I can try different algorithms as well, however still curious why it behaves this way. I assumed solutions are cloned during the optimization and I'm using different solvers so there should be no dependency. I'll keep on digging :-)

Comment: Spot on. ACC gets worse increasing the number of threads. 8 threads 40K, 4 threads 46K, 2 threads 52K. Is this the normal behaviour? I can put the code through a profile and check if there is a bottleneck somewhere, any suggestion appreciated here :-) Last time I profiled my code the only method standing out was my score calculation function (as I would expect), however I prefer to understand what is going on on the cloudbalance example - it' easier/cleaner to reproduce.